# passing address as a function parameter in web3

Tags: web3js

I've this contract that gets 'address' type variable as input parameter to function and sets it to a variable. This works fine in Remix. I'm trying to call this using web3js and am getting an `Uncaught Error: invalid address` error. Is there any work arounds / best design practices to get this done?

Contract:

```
mapping (address => bool) public lakeApprover;

function addForestApprover(address _forestApprover) public onlyOwner {
    forestApprover[_forestApprover] = true;
}
```

Web3js function

```
function addLakeApprover() {

    var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);

    var accountToAdd = document.getElementById('idAccount').value;      
    var accountToSubmit = web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],'',300);

    var txHash = myContractInstance.addForestApprover(accountToAdd, {'from':accountToSubmit,'gas':47000}, 
        function (err, res) { 
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err + "\n Response: " + res); 
            var txnReceipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(res);
            document.getElementById("idHashDetails").innerHTML = "<br> Block Number: " + txnReceipt.blockNumber
                                                                + "<br> Status: " + txnReceipt.status
                                                                //+ "<br> Status-ascii: " + web3.toAscii(txnReceipt.status)
                                                                + "<br> Transaction Hash: " + JSON.stringify(res);
                                                                ;
        }
    });
}
```

Hardcoded value and console print

```
    function addLakeApprover() {

        var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
        var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);

        var accountToAdd = "0x0B4a064e35f51aB6884E90B8F3953074a8C7F292";
        var accountToSubmitNOC = web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],'',300);

        console.log("accountToAdd value = "  + accountToAdd);
        var txHash = myContractInstance.addForestApprover ( accountToAdd, 
        {'from':accountToSubmitNOC,'gas':47000} , 
            function (err, res) { 
            if(!err) {
                console.log("Error: " + err + "\n Response: " + res); 
                }
        });
    }
```

Response for hardcoded value code

```
accountToAdd 0x0B4a064e35f51aB6884E90B8F3953074a8C7F292
web3.js:3914 Uncaught Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (web3.js:3914)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (web3.js:3740)
    at web3.js:5015
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Method.formatInput (web3.js:5014)
    at Method.toPayload (web3.js:5040)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (web3.js:5065)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (web3.js:4124)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (web3.js:4207)
    at addLakeApprover (Admin_screen.html:39)
```

Comment: @Ismael is right, the `unlockAccount` function doesn't return the unlocked account because unlocking accounts is done inside your node. just use the account you unlocked `web3.eth.accounts[0]`

Comment: @Ismael 'from':accountToSubmit <- is the owner account that created contract and since there is a state change, a from and gas values are provided. I'm trying to 'add' the 'accountToAdd' (which is selected from dropdown in html page) into the lakeApprover variable in contract.

Comment: Can you confirm the web3 version you are using?

Comment: I assume `accountToAdd` doesn't have the value you expect it to. Please log the value and take a look. (Share here if you can.) Try hardcoding `var accountToAdd = '0x123abc...';` to confirm.

Comment: var accountToAdd = document.getElementById('idAccount').value; <-- Did a console.log and got a string type value like 0x123abc (since I choose it from dropdown, which is the list of accounts from web3 that gets added up during page load)

Comment: @smarx - edited the question. prashant - web3.version.api  is "0.20.5"

Comment: And what's the value of `accountToSubmitNOC`? I'm not sure what (if anything) `web3.personal.unlockAccount` is supposed to return.

Comment: (Try using `web3.eth.accounts[0]` as the `from` address instead.)

Comment: Found the issue.    *** var accountToSubmit = web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],'',300);*** this is just holding 'true'. So, I unlocked the account first and set the accountToSubmit to web3.eth.accounts[0] and it worked!!  Sorry guys!!