# How can geth access contract variables through the console?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, cli

I'm using the Mist wallet just to display the contents of the contract.
Bellow, you can see the code to access the contract function (submitUnits) and the result of the LoadScript when I run in the console.

[image: call_function.js] call_function.js
In the last commented row, you can see the value I want to print (100).

[image]
Mist wallet

[image]

However it always returns this hex number. How can i get the Total Units that is mentioned in the wallet screenshot?

The code of the contract is this:

```
contract UCounter {
mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;
uint256 public TotalUnits;

function submitUnits(uint256 Units) returns (uint ){
    UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;
    TotalUnits = Units;
    return TotalUnits;
}
```

}

Hope someone could help.
Thanks.

Comment: 0x2c1e75ec... is the function you are sending, not the result of the function

Comment: please give the code of the contract otherwise it is hard to debug. e.g.: is the function that you call `constant`?

Comment: @ValidityLabs-Sebastian I update the code up in the contract code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function [getData](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) return function call parameters encoded together with the function signature.

From the snippet of your abi `submitUnits` is **not** constant has input parameter of type `uint256`. The output type is cropped, but in this case since `submitUnits` is a [transaction not a call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call), and for transaction we can recover the return value.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) to execute a transaction we have to do:

```
var txid = MyContractInstance.submitUnits.sendTransaction(parameter, { from: eth.accounts[3] });
console.log(txid);
```

And you have to wait until the transaction is mined in the blockchain.

To read a variable, or call a constant method you have to make a call

```
MyContractInstance.TotalUnits.call(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Yes I understood @Ismael , but with the transaction I alway can send values to my contract. What i'm looking for is through the geth console access  the TotalUnits variable. How can I return the value of the Transaction? I have updated the post with the wallet contract.

Answer (score 0):

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt (address, position)
```

Here `address` is address of your smart contract, and `position` is state variable position, in your case position=1 because `TotalUnits` is the second variable in your contract, and variables are numbered starting from zero.