# How to store value (string or hex) in ethereum blockchain / transaction?

Tags: blockchain, storage, python, web3.py

I have been looking through various tutorials (many of them outdated or with broken links) to figure out how to store and retrieve a simple string or hex value in the ETH blockchain. For my purposes (and intended application I am developing) it would be  best to be able to interface with the blockchain via Python.

I have tried using web3 and pyethereum with not much success. The furthest I have gotten is using the following code with the web3 interface.

What pieces am I missing and how can I properly store and retrieve a value on the ETH blockchain?

**How do I create a contract and store / retrieve a value from it?**

```
def eth_black_magic(hex_value):

    web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545')) # what URL should I point at?

    user1 = 'xxx' # what goes here?
    user2  = 'xxx' # what goes here?

    transaction = {'from': user2, 'to':user1, 'data': hex_value}

    transaction_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction(transaction)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a contract with a constant and a getter method ?

Comment: Are you trying to send data from one person to another? Maybe you want something like Whisper. It sounds like you might want to ask for help with your approach first, rather than the mechanics. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am not trying to send data from one person to another. I want to store a small string or hex value with a client and retreieve it with the same client.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of how to do a basic contract with web3.py?

Comment: In my answer, It shows how to write a contract in solidity, you'll need a remix like tool to deploy them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general approach could look like:

1. Create a contract that has a variable, say `uint public val`
2. Add a method on the contract that sets that variable, say `setVal(uint)`
3. Generate the contract ABI
4. Initialize `Web3(...)`, with a connection to your client
5. Create a contract object with the source code
6. Deploy the contract with `contract.deploy()`
7. Use the ABI and deployed address to create a Contract object in web3

`remix` could be a good option for steps 1-3. You can use `web3.py` for steps 4-7. Docs and tutorials should exist for all the individual steps.

Now, you are all set up with a deployed contract. You can get and set `val` in python with:

- Set the variable with `contract.transact().setVal(1337)`
- Get the variable with `contract.call().val()`

Comment: @carver won't `call()` work if method is causing changes to variables ?

say I do `contract.call().setVal(str)`.

is `transact()` a need here?

Comment: No @Shanthakumar, check out: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

Answer (score 2):

Deploy a contract with the value you want to store as constant.

```
contract C {
    string constant text = "abc";

    function getMystr() constant returns (string) {
        return mystr;
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the value by calling the `getMystr()` function.