# How to add two integer values using addition function in solidity using smart contracts?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract addition {

    address creator;
    uint a;
    uint b;
    uint c;

    function addition() public 
    {
        creator = msg.sender;                                // msg is a global variable
        uint c = uint a + uint b; //here i am getting an error that expected token semicolon got identifier
    }

    function addition() constant returns (uint) 
    {
        return uint c;
    }

    /**********
     Standard kill() function to recover funds 
     **********/

    function kill()
    { 
        if (msg.sender == creator)
            suicide(creator);  // kills this contract and sends remaining funds back to creator
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use the SafeMath library functions, this is the addition fucntion:

```
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
      }
```

to add:

```
c =a.add(b);
```

Note: If you don't want to use SafeMath (which you should), here is corrected syntax for your original code:

```
address creator;
uint a;
uint b;
uint c;

function addition() public 
{
    creator = msg.sender;                                // msg is a global variable
    uint c = a + b; //here i am getting an error that expected token semicolon got identifier
}
```

The difference is that you don't put the type of a variable when referring to it, only when declaring it.

link: [SafeMath library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to declare `uint c` the first time — after that you just refer to it as `c`.

`function addition() public {
  creator = msg.sender;
  c = a + b;
}`

There were a few other errors in your code, which I fixed in the following fiddle:

https://ethfiddle.com/O1z7aGXF3Y

You can play around with it there and see that it adds the integers as expected.

Comment: Thanx but i have run your updated code in remix it is not returning 3. ?

Comment: You have to run the `addition` function first, which adds the two integers. Then check the `getResult` function

Comment: @DeepakBaberwal You cannot return a value from a transaction see this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract AddInteger{
  uint private c;

function addition(uint _a, uint _b) public constant returns(uint)
  {
     c = _a+_b;
     return c;
  } 
}
```