# instance.balanceOf(...).call is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I have ERC20 standard token functions in my code...I´m trying to test the function `balanceOf(address _owner)` with a javascript test on truffle but I have the following problem:

```
 TypeError: ovxet.balanceOf(...).call is not a function
  at test/test1.js:48:46
```

It´s weird, because I always pay attention on how I define the functions in the code and how I have to call them...

I´ve tried in my test in both ways (async/await and promise chaning) but the result is the same "is not a function":

```
it("should call balance", function() {
    account1 = accounts[0];
    return OVXET.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        ovxet = instance;
        return ovxet.balanceOf(account1).call({from: account1});
    }).then(function(balance){
        console.log(balance);
    });
});
```

And this async/await call inside another promise:

```
    var balance2 = await ovxet.balanceOf(account1).call({from: account1});
    console.log("balance using erc20 function: " + balance2.toNumber());
```

Here you have the code inside the .sol script:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
    return _sumBalances(_owner);
}
```

It´s really strange because It´s so easy coding-function...so I am really frustrating with this situation...

This is the ABI part related to this function:

```
{
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "_owner",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "name": "balanceOf",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "balance",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Truffle v4.xx you should be able to call a functions like this

```
return OVXET.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    ovxet = instance;
    return ovxet.balanceOf.call(account1, {from: account1});
}).then(function(balance){
    console.log(balance);
});
```

The syntax is `contract.method.call(param1, param2, ..)`.

Comment: Is it recommended to make function calls like that? I've seen it done in jquery plugins as well. Are there some benefits?

Comment: There are not official recommendations, you can use any library/framework you are comfortable with.

Comment: I've done some digging, and while writing tests if you use `contract.method.call()` then a transaction is not actually executed on the test network. However if you call the method like `contract.method()` then a transaction will be executed on the test network. So using `.call()` will actually allow you to run tests on return values without executing transactions on the network.

Comment: See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call to understand when to use them. Create a new question if you have more doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`Let balance = Token.balanceOf(accountB).then(b => { return b.toNumber() })`

Comment: I think you are missing an await.