# Retrieve the value returned by a function which was invoked with 'transact'

Tags: solidity, python, web3.py

I am using Python `web3` in order to deploy and test a Solidity contract.

Here are my initial steps:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3 import RPCProvider
from json import loads

eth = Web3(RPCProvider()).eth
abi = open(ABI_FILE_NAME).read()
bin = open(BIN_FILE_NAME).read()
transaction = {'from':eth.accounts[0]}

contract = eth.contract(abi=loads(abi),bytecode=bin)
tx_hash  = contract.deploy(transaction=transaction)
address  = eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)['contractAddress']
handle   = contract(address).transact(transaction)
```

At this point, I invoke a function in the contract:

```
tx_hash = handle.some_func()
```

And this is what I get when I call `eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`:

```
{
    'transactionHash'   : '0x...',
    'transactionIndex'  : 0,
    'blockHash'         : '0x...',
    'blockNumber'       : 3710,
    'gasUsed'           : 72597,
    'cumulativeGasUsed' : 72597,
    'contractAddress'   : None,
    'logs'              : [],
    'status'            : 1
}
```

How can I retrieve the actual value that `some_func` has returned?

I found [a very detailed answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/770/16043) which seems to refer to this issue, but I have not been able to conclude the actual steps required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no "return value" for a transaction. There are two typical patterns to simulate a return value:

1. Mutate the state via a transaction and then read the resulting state by calling a `view` function. (Note that this gives you the state at the time you call the `view` function, not necessarily the state right after the transaction, since other transactions may have come between.)
2. Mutate the state via a transaction and emit an `event` that's observed by the caller.

Depending on your scenario, one or the other may be a more natural fit.

Comment: Yes, I've already gathered this information more or less. The first option is not acceptable, due to the reason that you mention explicitly. I need to dive into the second option. Do you have a good coding example? Both sides (Solidity and Python-web3) would be great. If not, then at least on the Solidity side. Thanks.

Comment: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events is pretty good, though it's Solidity+JavaScript, not Solidity+Python.

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to achieve this purpose. Practical answer given below yours.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I was able to resolve this problem:

1. In the Solidity contract, just before returning, I generate an `event` which contains the value about to be returned.
2. In the Python code, I extract the returned value with:

   `retVal = eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)['logs'][0]['data']`

This value happens to be an hexadecimal string in my case, so I use `int(retVal,16)` in order to obtain the corresponding integer value.