# When should we call( ), watch( ) or get ( ) an event?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I find this concept to be very confusing, when should I be using *watch*, *call* or *get* to listen to an event? how are they different and when should they be used?

```
var event1 = newInst.getSupplier({'OwnAdd': someaddr},{fromBlock:'latest, toBlock:'pending'}, function(error, result) {
    console.log("listening bro1");
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.args);
});
```

How will the output differ when I change the call or watch or get?

Answer (score 0):

getSupplier - if it is a view or pure smart contract function will defer to the call (so they are the same)
If there is a state change it will defer to sendTransaction

The call should return the value immediately from the blockchain - there is no mining involved.

watching or filtering will wait for an event to be added to the logs - if that event is being emitted by the smart contract. That is if you use watch on the filter.

getting the logs by means of calling get on your filter will returns the logs that match the filter.

more detail here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods

Answer (score 0):

`call()` is a read-only operation that returns a value but can't change the state. This behavior can be suggested by the contract itself. Have a look here: [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call/770#770)

`sendTransaction()` *can* change the contract state, *does* return a transaction hash but *can't change* the state.

Also, this might be helpful if the foregoing is impenetrable: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

`watch()` is for event logs in contracts, not functions. Logs are an important aspect of contract design. Software clients can learn a lot about happenings inside contracts *if* the logs are well-designed.

Hope it helps.