# Truffle Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

Issue:Not able to return the input string(ofcourse it works in remix). Below is the contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
    contract samplecontract {
    function viewuserName(string name) public returns(string){
    return (name);
}   
}
```

index.html:

```
<input id="txtdummyName" type="text" placeholder="Enter  sometext" />
<button id="btnViewUserName" onclick="App.viewUserName()">View userName</button>
```

when i click on the "View userName" button, ie., when i try to call the viewUserName in app.js in truffle it logs Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert. I tried the following commented ways too.! Also tried console.log(v.toString()) How to identify the issue?

app.js:

```
viewUserName:function(){    
var sometext=document.getElementById("txtdummyName").value;
sampleinstance.deployed().then(function (instance) {
  console.log(sometext); 
  // return instance.viewuserName.call(sometext).then(function(v){
  //   console.log(v);
  // })
  // return instance.viewuserName.call(sometext,{gas: 540000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v){
  //   console.log(v);
  // })
  // return instance.viewuserName(sometext,{gas: 540000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v){
  //     console.log(v);
  // })
  // return instance.viewuserName(sometext).then(function(v){
  //   console.log(v);
  // })
  return instance.viewuserName(sometext,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0],gas: 1540000}).then(function(v){
    console.log(v);
  })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: hey , instead of trying to send arguments from HTML, send a static string. if it doesn't work then it is your contract's problem.

Comment: You function `viewuserName` doesn't have the `view` or `pure` modifier. So when you call it it will create a transaction instead of a call and transactions never return a value. See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call. You need to use `view` or `pure` in your function definition.

Comment: More over, return name shoud be enough. brackets not needed.

Comment: sending a static string didn't work

Comment: view or pure modifier also didn't work

Comment: @user2865883 are you sure you recompiled after adding those modifiers?

Comment: Joel, if we use truffle recompiling needs only when there is change in the contract. save will automatically refreshes the browser with app.js code

Comment: Ismael, you are saying i have to create a transaction rather than making a call. I am new to this so what exactly should i do for getting the name as the output in truffle?

Comment: @user2865883 Your function `viewuserName` doesn't have the `pure` or `view` modifiers. Then it will be interpreted as a transaction when used and since transactions do not return values you will not be able to get the value. If you want to read values then the function has to be declared as `pure` or `view`. If after the modification it doesn't work it is likely you are still using the old contract or the abi was not updated. To force truffle to recompile you can delete the build directory and redeploy your contracts (newer version of truffle might have fixed that bug).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ismael, Making the function view and return instance.viewuserName(sometext,{gas: 540000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v){
        console.log(v.toString());
      }) in truffle app.js helped me out.