# What is the correct way of launching contract from contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

Simplified version of my contracts works

`MyContract`

- `await contract.methods.info().call()` Works indicating that there is
  no error in the `MyContract` itself.

`Launchpad`

- There is no issues when launching `MyContract` using launchpad contract since I get address to a newly published contract.

The problem is that when I call the contract created with Launchpad contract in JavaScript I get the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI: 0x

```
contract MyContract {
  function info() external view returns(uint min, uint max) {
    return(1, 2);
  }
}

contract Launchpad {

 function launch() public returns(address) {
   MyContract myContractAddress = new MyContract();
   return myContractAddress;
 }

}
```

Comment: "since I get address to a newly published contract" <-- How? Transactions don't have return values, so when you call `launch`, there's no way for you to get back the address of the new contract. The typical solution is to log an event and read that from JavaScript.

Comment: Or you can just add `pure` to the declaration of function `launch`.

Comment: return myContractAddress gives me the address to the new contract

Comment: Only inside the blockchain. If you want to get it on the off-chain side (for example, via web3.js), then you need to decode the hash that it returns. That is, of course, unless the function is either `pure` or `view`, in which case, you can indeed obtain the return value on the off-chain side without any decoding required. So as I mentioned on the previous comment, just add `pure` (which you can, since the function does not access any global variables).

Comment: const foo = await contract.methods.launch();

Comment: const response = await foo.send({from: address, gas: '600000'})

Comment: which returns =>  response.to (is this not the contract address? )

Comment: Right. So now `foo` holds a hash of the transaction receipt, which you need to decode. And by the way, since you do not emit an event which contains `myContractAddress` in the `launch` function, this value is not going to be available to you even after you decode the hash.

Comment: so what is response.to ?

Comment: Just tested it in remix and I think you are right, apparently I was logging something else Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

Comment: Definitely not, @goodvibration actually solved my problem