# Can Solidity smart contracts send transactions on Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, transactions

I am trying to figure out whether Solidity smart contracts deployed on the Ethereum main net can send transactions. In other terms, can the address of a smart contract appear as the sender of a transaction?

I've already read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call) thread and the definition of Transaction presented in the [Ethereum Yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), but I am still quite confused...

Answer (score -1):

Contracts can send transactions.  If you use the transfer function inside a smart contract, it will show on "Internal Transactions" on Etherscan.

Comment: This is incorrect. Contracts cannot send transactions. "Internal transactions" is a misnomer for calls between contracts.

Comment: @smarx "Internal transactions" are value transfers

Comment: @Nulik If you mean that the tab labeled "internal transactions" on Etherscan shows only the calls between contracts that include attached ether, I _think_ you're right. But I haven't seen any documentation from them on the subject.

Comment: In any case, they're certainly not transactions.

Comment: @smarx, of course they aren't transactions. I just meant, a proper concept would be "value transfer", in fact, Nick Jonson from Ethereum Foundation was the first to call them this way in his tool "etherquery"