# How does MetaMask knows that a precondition of a contract will fail?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, tokens, metamask

I'm working with an standard ERC20 token, I have a transfer function:

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

I have an address A that has 20 of my ERC20 tokens, and I'm using web3.js to send transactions to a smart contract that is deployed on a Geth private node. MetaMask is intercepting those invocations.

I'm curious about the behaviour of MetaMask in these two scenarios:

1. Send 19 tokens from address A to adddress B, the transaction succeeds, now A has 1 token
2. Try to send 21 tokens from address A to address B, metamask shows this message:

[image: MetaMask notification]

It is as if MetaMask knows that the precondition of the contract will fail:

```
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
```

I'm curious to know if MetaMask has its own state of the contract and can determine if a transaction will fail or not, previous to invoking the contract, or while it is invoking the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It steps through the transaction in a read-only mode as part of the gas estimation process. It can see when the transaction is likely to fail.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, is there any place where i can read about that? Im curious about how Metamask does the read-only step through

Comment: MetaMask doesn't do it. It calls [`eth_estimateGas`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas) on the Ethereum node it's talking to. This does much the same thing as `eth_call`... it executes the transaction locally to measure the gas usage and then just throws away the side effects.

Comment: I agree with Steve about the detailed sequence. Gas estimation works by stepping over the code. You can also invoke it any time you like to explore function responses. Have a look over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

Comment: Ok, so metamask calls eth_estimateGas, the Geth node invoke the transfer function of my contract but discards any modifications on the blockchain, so the eth_estimateGas doesnt affect the blockchain state. Thats make sense. Thank u guys