# Ethereum Remix IDE Not Returning Values

Tags: solidity, remix

Here I am having an issue where the values are not appearing to function correctly in the Remix IDE browser.

I am trying to have a buyer where they can transfer funds to each other, and the seller can add a description and retrieve the description.

The issue I am finding is when I execute the at the address I can't appear to get the amount from the Buyers contract. The only thing that happens when I click on getAmount it executes but returns nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code I entered into Remix:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Buyer {
        //event LogDescription(address sender, uint amount);
        uint  amount;
        mapping (address => uint) balances;

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
            //if (amount < 10 ether){
                balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
                balances[receiver] += amount;
                //LogDescription(receiver, amount);
            //}
    }

   function getAmount() returns(uint) {
        return(amount);
    }

}

    contract Seller{
        string description;

        Buyer bartscontract;

        function SetDescription(string _description) public {
            description = _description;
            //LogDescription(msg.sender, msg.value, description);
        }
        function getDescription() constant public returns(string) {
            return description;
        }




    }
```

Here are some screenshots for send and receive ether for further analysis.
Below is for Sending 1 Ether to the address:
[image]

Below is for trying to get or view ether sent to the specified address.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function `getAmount` do not modify the storage so you can mark as a `view`

```
function getAmount() public view returns (uint) {
    return(amount);
}
```

Remix will create a call when you use the function `getAmount`.

See this question: [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call) to understand the difference between a transaction and a call.

Comment: Indeed you need the view modifier. 
I prefer using external/internal over public.

Answer (score 1):

The other question I have here is why no value is given and the console just responds back with a call to Buyer.getAmount()?
Then no value is actually given back.
Is this an error or glitch?

Comment: If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question.