# Calculator Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, view

Below is my smart contract code for calculator.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Calculator{

    uint result=10;

    function Calculator() public
    {

    }

    function getResult() public view returns (uint)
    {
        return result;
    }

    function addition(uint num) public
    {
        result=result+num;

    }

    function sub(uint num) public
    {
        result = result - num;
    }

    function mult(uint num) public
    {
        result =result*num;
    }

    function div(uint num) public
    {
        result = result/num;
    }

    }
```

Here what is the significance of `view` keyword in below function?

```
function getResult() public view returns (uint)
```

My observation is:

1. If I do not specify `view` keyword, remix browser is not showing me results.
2. If I specify the `view` keyword, I can see the result on UI.

But still I want to understand the significance of `view` in solidity.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

Answer (score 1):

A non-view function executes a transaction on the blockchain.

You can use the return-value directly only in the on-chain (i.e., by calling this function from another function in the same contract or from another function in another contract).

When you call it in the off-chain (i.e., using some web3 client), then you do not get the return-value directly, but a transaction receipt, which you can then use in order to check the status of the transaction executed.

Comment: I think you meant to say the view functions (off-chain) return values but don't update the state and the non-view functions (on-chain) update the state but don't return value (to EOA). ;-)

Comment: @RobHitchensB9lab: I said only the second half of your statement, because I figured that he/she were having difficulties understanding why they were unable to obtain the return-value.