# Token Transferring issue to the respective winner

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumj

My code has a function which randomly select a subscriber from the list and all of the sum of the tokens should transfer to the winner account address. but unfortunately it is not working for me.

please somebody advice..

```
function WeeklyW1() public  view returns (address,uint, uint){

    uint randWinAddr = uint(block.blockhash(block.number - 1)) % subscriberListW1.length;
    winner = subscriberListW1[randWinAddr];

    for (uint i=0; i<subscriberListW1.length; i++) {
    uint value = (_balances[subscriberListW1[i]] * subscriberListW1.length) * 20/100;      
    uint value1 = ((_balances[subscriberListW1[i]] * subscriberListW1.length)
                    - (_balances[subscriberListW1[i]] * subscriberListW1.length) * 20/100);

    _balances[subscriberListW1[randWinAddr]] += value1 ;
    _balances[owner] += value;

    //these below are not working...
    owner.transfer(address(value).balance);
    winner.transfer(address(value1).balance);

    //It is just for verification purpose 
    return (winner,_balances[subscriberListW1[randWinAddr]],_balances[owner]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working, you need to remove `view` from the function as only then your function will make changes in the state. If problem still persists, please share the error message.

For more details, see : [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)