# To store and retreive data using geth!

Tags: geth-debugging

I am trying to deploy my contract using geth.

Contract goes like this :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract hier {

     uint i;
    uint ur=0;
    bytes15[2][20] public UserRole;

    function user_role_assignment(bytes15[] memory a) public
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)    
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            UserRole[ur][0]=a[i];
            else{
            UserRole[ur][1]=a[i];

            ur=ur+1;
            }
        }  
    }

bytes15 public result;

function checkAccess( bytes15 username ) public {

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)    
        { 
            if(UserRole[i][0]==username)
               result = UserRole[i][1];
       }
}

function RESULT() public view  returns(bytes15)
 {

    return result;

}

}
```

When I pass array through function user_role_assignment, values are not stored. (Everything is working fine in Remix)
Why is it happening?

Someone please help!

Not only this, even simple function which just store value in a variable is not working in geth but working fine when I run on remix.

Eg:

```
contract Example{

uint public i = 0;


function store() {

 i = 100;

}

function check() public returns(uint){

 returns i;

}
```

After running store and check functions in geth, i values didn't change...
Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: How do you call the contract functions from geth?

Comment: In the 2nd contract named Example   :      example.store.call( ) , example is the variable in which bin of the contract is stored.

Comment: If you use `example.store.call()` it will NOT modify the contract storage. You have to use `example.store()` instead. See this question for the difference between a call and a transaction https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call.