# Truffle js test a call with arguments

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I am trying to testa a smart contract function that receives an arg. I'm using truffle javascript tests, this is the smart contract function, very simple:

```
function addExam(string memory hash) public returns (string memory examProfessorHash) {
        // save the exam hash and link it with the professors address
        professorsExam[msg.sender] = hash;

        return hash;
    }
```

As you can see, it receives a hash as an argument. Now I want to test this in Truffle js:

```
 it("should add an exam to the exams list", async () => {
        // This should test the complete functionality
        let hash_test = "fB03aA5E2E71De1470ae2";
        let instance = await Exam.deployed();
        let hash = instance.addExam().call(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]});
        assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test, "Not returning the correct address")
    })
```

I can improve the test of course, but first, I need to be able to call the function and pass it an argument, how do I do that? The code above doesnt work, it gives me an error:

> Error: Invalid number of parameters for "addExam". Got 0 expected 1!

Comment: Your function modifies the contract storage so it requires a transaction and not a call. See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call for the difference. To execute as transaction `await instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]})`, but transaction do not return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different issues here:

First, the syntax `addExam().call(...)` is incorrect.

It should be either `addExam.call(...)` or `addExam(...)`.

Second, the usage of `call` by itself is incorrect.

Since function `addExam` changes the state of your contract, you should use `sendTransaction`.

---

In short, change this:

```
instance.addExam().call(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]})
```

To this:

```
instance.addExam.sendTransaction(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]})
```

Or to this:

```
instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]})
```