# How to print the value of encoded getter functions of contract

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, nodejs

**UPDATED:** Sorry for Inconvenience, I have **updated** **all my question** and accept my apology , being naive user.

I have encoded getter functions of my contract i.e. `0x27e235e30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...............`. In this encoded function, there may be one, two or three arguments lets say address, string, uint. Such function may return one/two values i.e. uint/string. Now I want to call that encoded function and get its return values. which then i print them on console and also save into my array. I am trying following code, which is printing receipt of my transaction, as expected. But I want to print/save return values (returned by contract function).

```
try {
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
        {from:account1,
        to:myContAddr,
        data: myFunc
            }).then(function(res){
              console.log("Normal Getter", res);
              myResult.push(res);
          });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(" Normal Getters: ERROR !"); 
    }
```

Should I have to decode such encoded function to extract arguments and methodID separately, and then call it ???

**Note**: A list of such encoded function is provided to me and also i have ABIs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102281/discussion-on-question-by-amir-ali-how-to-print-the-value-of-encoded-getter-func).

Comment: The return value can be obtained for view functions if you use call https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call. For regular transactions it cannot be obtained easily and you have to trace them, the recommended alternative is to use events instead of return for transactions.

Comment: but i have encoded all values ... functionname and its parameters are encoded ... ,  please read my question againg...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const ABI =
[
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [ { name: 'caller', type: 'address' } ],
        name: 'getTotalSupply',
        outputs: [ { name: '', type: 'uint256' } ],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function'
    }
];

async function getTotalSupply(myContAddr, callerAddr) {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, myContAddr);
    return await contract.methods.getTotalSupply(callerAddr).call();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts.. BUT.. i have this encoded getter function. Let me explain.  I have ABI from where i can extract ALL thing about my function/contract, except the VALUES for my function parameters. For example, my function take three arguemnts (1. address, 2. string, and 3.uint256), then how could i call that function with some arguments. Therefore, for arguments values i must have to consult the provided list of encoded function (with arguments values)...  So, in this case your answer is not applicable..

Comment: @AmirAli: That's NOT what your question says!

Comment: I have made another update.. now