# I got this error during truffle testing. AssertionError: it returns true: expected { Object (tx, receipt, ...) } to equal true

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache, mocha

**DappToken.sol**

```
   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public  returns (bool success){

    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value); 

    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return (true);
```

**DappToken.js file**

```
it('transfer token ownership', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        tokenInstance = instance;

    something larger than the sender's balance
    return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'error message must contain revert');

        return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 2500, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(success) {
        assert.equal(success, true, 'it returns true');



    return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 2500, {from: accounts[0] });     
    }).then(function(receipt) {


        assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'should be the "Transfer" event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._from, accounts[0], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred from');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._to, accounts[1], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred to');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value, 2500, 'logs the transfer amount');


    return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 2500, 'adds the amount to the receiving account');
    return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);    
    }).then(function(balance) {
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 7500, 'deducts the amount from the sending account');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the problem is in the assert

```
    return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 2500, { from: accounts[0] });
}).then(function(success) {
    assert.equal(success, true, 'it returns true');
```

You are comparing the return of a transaction against true. Transactions do not return anything, calls return the value.
See here for an explanation about the difference [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call).

A possible solution is to check the status of the transaction in the receipt:

```
    return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 2500, { from: accounts[0] });
}).then(function(result) {
    assert.ok(result.receipt.status, 'it returns true');
```

A better solution for token is to verify the emission of the event.

Comment: I had a similar issue and the solution was to verify the emission of the event.