# How to listen to ERC721 approval event with ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, events

I am trying to listen to an approval event in an ERC721 token. On approval, I want to call a function.

```
const approving = new ethers.Contract(gift.address, abi, signer)
await approving.approve(contractAddress, gift.tokenID)
approving.on('Approval', async() => {
      //await some function
})
```

This was the syntax that I used and I am fairly certain that it worked for a while. Now, however, I get the error: "no matching event (argument="name", value="Approval", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.4)".

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/how-to-listen-to-contract-events-using-ethers-js Does this help?

Comment: @MadeInDreams That's where I started but to be honest I didn't really understand how to set up the parameters inside topics.

Answer (score 0):

From docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events

```
// This filter could also be generated with the Contract or
// Interface API. If address is not specified, any address
// matches and if topics is not specified, any log matches
filter = {
    address: "ADDRESS_OF_NFT_COLLECTION",
    topics: [
        utils.id("Approval(address,address,uint256)")
    ]
}
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    // Emitted whenever approval is given
})
```

This is cuz `Approval` event from IERC721 has following arguments:

```
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed approved, uint256 indexed tokenId);
```

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol#L20

Remember that there is also function `setApprovalForAll` and different event is emitted `ApprovalForAll`.