# Is it possible to calculate the gas costs of a transaction exactly upfront?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, gas-estimate

In the Ethereum wallet there are the estimated gas costs. Why is it only an estimate? Is is possible to calculate the gas costs precisely upfront?

Comment: Related http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: **it depends, for some transactions state changes might change the pre calculated gas costs**.

It is possible to calculate the gas costs of every transaction given the current state. However - since the state can change until the transaction is finally executed the state can change.

Consider the following code:

```
if a = true:
    cheap computation
else:
    expensive computation
```

Now it is possible that the state of a will change. However - there are a lot of transactions that have always the same costs independent of the state. E.g. a regular value transfer to an account without associated code will always have a fixed cost.