# How much ether I should have in my wallet to send 1 ETH to an ICO

Tags: transactions, ether, out-of-gas, fees

I need to send 1 ETH to an ICO. I have 1 ETH in my wallet. I am using myetherwallet.com

Question .

1. If I send 1ETH to the contract address, will it fail for insufficient fee amount ?
2. How much do I need to have in my wallet to send 1 ETH to the contract address ? Is it ( 1ETH +  transaction Fee i.e, Gas) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gonna be a normal transaction anyway, whether it is to send to an ICO or not.

Hence the transaction needs to have more than 1 ETH in your wallet, the additional is the transaction cost.

> If I send 1ETH to the contract address, will it fail for insufficient
>   fee amount ?

Yes, it's going to fail because you don't have enough to pay the transaction fee.

> How much do I need to have in my wallet to send 1 ETH to the contract
>   address ? Is it ( 1ETH + transaction Fee i.e, Gas) ?

Yes, it'll be 1 ETH + transaction fee and the transaction fee depends on the gas price you select.

> What happen when transaction fails ? the (transaction amount +
>   transaction Fee ) will be returned back ?

If you face a Out Of Gas Error, the transaction amount will be rolled back, but not the transaction fee. Transaction fee until the execution got failed will be charged anyway. Referring to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5854/16301) will also be useful.

Comment: What happen when transaction fails ?  the (transaction amount + transaction Fee ) will be returned back ?

Comment: transaction amount is always rolled back, but not the transaction fee. Transaction fee until the execution got failed will be charged anyway - that's the award that miner gets for processing the transaction until it fails. you mat refer [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/what-happens-if-transaction-runs-out-of-gas-before-transaction-completes)  and the [post here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4b3a47/what_are_the_consequences_of_running_out_of_gas/)