# Automated gas cost calculation in Hardhat?

Tags: gas-estimate, hardhat

### Context

I've learned from [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-gas-costs-of-a-transaction-exactly-upfront) that it is not (always) possible to compute the gas-costs of an arbitrary solidity contract `a.sol` because the amount of computation that it takes may depend on the input it receives from the other smart contracts that it interacts with.

However, in for example the HardHat or Waffle test framework, one can feed your smart contract `a.sol`, all of its other smart contracts. Yet I did not yet find a clear indication of the gas costs of that contract. (After the tests were completed, before it was deployed to main-net).

So, assuming one has enough coverage in the tests (contracts), one could get an accurate enough range of the gas costs as a function of various input (test) contracts.

### Question

Are there applications/code solutions (in HardHat) that instantly give the gas costs of a contract based on specific input contracts? (Ideally, a minimal working example (MWE) of parameterised plot based on certain input variables could be presented).

Comment: I think eth-gas-reporter has some functionality like this, check it out. I don't remember exactly which statistics it gives you, but it might be what you want.

Comment: Could you use a mainnet fork and deploy the contract to it and test the gas costs? This should be quite accurate on mainnet at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Remix IDE for such aim. It provides rich UI to compile, deploy and run the contract. In console it publish relevant information from EVM including gas cost on deploy and transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it is definitely better than nothing. From what I understand, I do think it misses the automated aspect a bit as I believe the IDE/UI is not a command line interface. If this assumption is invalid, please let me know.

Comment: Hardhat support gas reporting 'out of the box'. Here is the command ```REPORT_GAS=true npx hardhat test```