# How to estimate gas for my function using web3 js only?

Tags: web3js, gas-estimate

Hi this is my solidity function

```
function closeBid(string _product) public{
  }
```

I want to estimate gas for this function so in web3 js I called this like

```
var gas = MyContract.closeBid().estimateGas("Coffee",{from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

But it throws `InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs()`. How can I estimate gas for this function because this function consumes lot of gas. I have to make sure availability of gas for calling this function. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, try in this way:

```
MyContract.closeBid.estimateGas("Coffee", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

Comment: Thank you. I more doubt. I got result of 32591, is this maximum gas that the function consumes. I mean whole function including array insertion deletion etc.

Comment: @e.k As the name implies, it's an estimate...a ballpark range based on what the function does.

Comment: Yes, because the transaction is executed inside the VM but not mined, so that's the gas that you gonna spend. But of course in the real environment depends what price you're going to pay for that gas. Higher is the gasPrice and more fast will be mined your transaction (and more expensive gonna be to execute it) lower will be the gasPrice and less you will spend (but it could also be not mined if it's too low). Follow this link it's explained https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/266/what-are-the-limitations-to-estimategas-and-when-would-its-estimate-be-considera

Answer (score 0):

You can run `estimateGas` without using a contract, this is useful when you don't have the ABI but got the input data and want to estimate gas cost before submitting the transaction, or if you just don't have the method name.

From Web3.eth `estimateGas` [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html?highlight=estimate%20gas#estimategas) -

```
web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
})
.then(console.log);
> "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015"
```