# What are the alternative methods of specifying gas price for contract execution?

Tags: transactions, gas-price, fees, meta-transactions

This is possibly a rhetoric question, but I didn't find an answer to it. There are excellent answers to similar questions from @eth [How much does it cost to use a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-much-does-it-cost-to-use-a-contract) and [When calling a smart contract function, who gets paid and how much does the caller pay?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10050/when-calling-a-smart-contract-function-who-gets-paid-and-how-much-does-the-call?rq=1)

Q1. Please validate the inputs and outputs of the following statement:

GIVEN All the following statements validate *true*:
1. Only transactions are mined.
2. Gas price "market" is non-deterministic (example: http://ethgasstation.info/)

THEN **One the the only acceptable** method of specifying gasPrice is for a transaction, before invocation by an external account, i.e. *before* the transaction is signed and submitted to blockchain.

Q2. Are there alternative methods of specifying gasPrice and what are their guarantees that that transaction will be mined?

Comment: You're correct that there's only one way to specify gasPrice.  If you're trying to do something related to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82/how-interact-with-ethereum-without-gas-ether then keep an eye on "[Meta Transactions](https://medium.com/uport/making-uport-smart-contracts-smarter-part-2-introducing-identitymanager-af656ba7441b)"