# Is the gas-limit as seen on ethstats measured in wei?

Tags: gas-limit

Simple question but I can't seem to find the answer online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Gas is a unit of computing work to run a Smart Contract. Running a function in a Smart Contract will consume a certain amount of gas. It's similar to the way a car trip will consume a certain amount of fuel.

Ether is used to pay for gas. Gas price is variable. There are good economically-based reasons for separating the measurement of work performed and the cost per unit of work.

More detailed information here: [What is "gas" and transaction fee in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-gas-and-transaction-fee-in-ethereum)

Hope it helps.

Comment: ahhh I see, i was thinking about it wrong