# myetherwallet.com is taking forever

Tags: myetherwallet

I sent a transaction over 6 hours ago from myetherwallet to an outside address with the site's suggested 21000 gas limit. Its up to over 1000 block confirmations but still has not completed, yet reduced myetherwallet by the transacted amount. How do I increase the gas limit to speed it up? Or must I just wait for it to complete? How can I cancel the transaction altogether?

Please help!

Comment: Do you have the transaction hash?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the gas limit will have no effect on the speed of your transaction, it might even slow it down. What you want to do is increase the gas price, MyEtherWallet has a gauge at the bottom right corner to adjust this setting :

[image]

Here is a detailed explanation of the difference between gas price and gas limit :
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/62/11390