# ethers.js - estimating gas limit

Tags: gas-limit, gas-estimate, ethers.js

Using the `ethers.js` library, how can I determine the gas limit when sending a transaction to a contract or deploying a new contract?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case?  What are you building, what exactly is the commission for?

Comment: For sending, I use npm ethers module

Comment: When you say commission, do you mean the fee paid to the miners?

Comment: For sending, I use npm ethers module. To send all funds , the formula for receiving the value field is used tx.value = balance - gasLimit * gasPrcie. But when the tx.data field is added, the transaction is not sent due to lack of funds

Comment: Yes "commission" = transaction fee

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is `eth_estimateGas` - I'm unsure how to do so with `ethers.js` but I will propose an edit to your question to make it clearer for others.

Comment: more generally, this may be useful - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/how-to-calculate-transaction-fee

Answer (score 2):

(The OP has commented on the question that they're looking for a way to estimate the [gas **price**](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#what-is-gas), not the [gas **limit**](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#what-is-gas-limit), this answer is based on that clarification.)

### Method 1

Ethers has a built-in function for estimating gas: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-estimateGas

Here's a copy of the snippet from the docs linked above:

```js
await provider.estimateGas({
  // Wrapped ETH address
  to: "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",

  // `function deposit() payable`
  data: "0xd0e30db0",

  // 1 ether
  value: parseEther("1.0")
});
// { BigNumber: "27938" }
```

You'll need to have a provider instantiated, and you'll also need to be able to pipe in the `to` address and the raw data. Here's a [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/122270/27270) to an answer about how to encode the raw data. This can be a bit of a hassle, so you may want to keep reading for another potential solution if you need this for a contract call.

### Method 2

Another way of accomplishing this for contract calls specifically uses a built-in contract method called `estimateGas`. (Link to [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/example/#erc20-meta-methods), you'll need to scroll down, but it's in that section)

Assume you have a contract you've instantiated inside Ethers as `foo`. If `foo` has a function `bar` (which takes 0 arguments), and you want to estimate the cost of calling `bar`, you can use:

```js
await foo.estimateGas.bar();
// { BigNumber: "34458" }
```

You also may want to take a look at the `callStatic` contract method (in the same section as the docs) if you're interested in more data than just the gas estimate.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation, see the [deployment](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#deployment) section from `contracts` module. The section provides an example of deploying a contract on `ropsten`. From the contract deployment [hash](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x159b76843662a15bd67e482dcfbee55e8e44efad26c5a614245e12a00d4b1a51), you can get the idea of different `gas` parameters:

Transaction Fee: `0.00181826 Ether ($0.000000)`

Gas Limit: `363,652`

Gas Used by Transaction: `363,652 (100%)`

Gas Price: `0.000000005 Ether (5 Gwei)`

You can read more about gas estimation from [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/194) and [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/515).

hope it will help.