Deploying Contracts with Multi-Sig Wallet via Safe-Global/Safe App Wallet & Hardhat: Need Guidance
I’m looking for assistance with deploying a contract using either safe-global or the Safe App wallet. My goal is to initiate the deployment with a multi-sig wallet via Hardhat scripts. Can anyone offer guidance or instructions on how to achieve this?

you can create a deployment transaction to submit to your safe using the protocol kit. You will then be able to approve this transaction using either the protocol kit's approveTransaction method or via the Safe{Wallet} UI. You could then encapsulate this logic in a hardhat script if you use the SDK.
You can also look into the Safe smart account repo for an example configuration on how Safe contracts are deployed with hardhat.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Thank you for the solution. Could you please explain how to create the transaction data that will be used to deploy the contract with an initializer function? This data will need to be passed into the approvalTransaction.

This is explored in this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/how-do-i-manually-encode-and-send-transaction-data
