# Digital asset management dapp using Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am new to ethereum and also I have tried out some examples for building smart contract using truffle and ganache. But I want to make Digital asset management dapp using ethereum.

Like, if have I have 50 person and 60 machines in organization, in that
 - one person is allocated to multiple machines
 - one machine can operate by only one person at a time
 - If any person wants to access the machine then current owner of that machine needs to releases that machine first.

So, all this information I need to store on blockchain.
Can anyone suggest how to at least start with this requieremnts, is it possible to do inside ethereum or any other blockchain network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality I don't see any reason to use blockchain for this. Everything would be (at least with current blockchain technology) a lot easier with "traditional" means (centralized database).

But in theory you can do it also in Ethereum blockchain. Essential building blocks would be:

- All users need some Ether to interact with the blockchain and pay for the transactions - you can't call the blockchain without paying fees for it. Or if you want to use a private blockchain, then private Ether (free). Check [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas) for more info
- All users need some gateway into the blockchain. MetaMask is probably the easiest currently. https://metamask.io/
- You need to write a smart contract inside the blockchain to contain the logic and state

As you're new to this, I recommend you first look at some general tutorials about how to build dApps in Ethereum. Don't real tutorials that are over a year old as the technology (or mostly the tools to access the blockchain) change rapidly. Here's one tutorial: https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2

Comment: Yes, I have already tried out that link tutorials which you have shared along with Part -1 as well as Part -2 and both are working fine.

But, I have shared my requirement in question, so for that I little bit confused that how to start.  If I will use ganache then it will only provide 10 demo accounts. How to do it ?

Comment: Start by writing the smart contract for this. Then continue with the user integration - how users can communicate with the smart contract (Metamask). Depending on your plans, you possibly don't need multiple Ethereum accounts - all users can use the same account for interaction, with different usernames (a concept between the contract and your outside-blockchain logic)

Comment: You mean it will be possible with ganache, right ? or we need to use another private blockchain ?

Comment: Yes, you can use ganache to create a private blockchain.

Comment: In your previous comment you have mentioned that "we don't need multiple Ethereum accounts - all users can use the same account for interaction, with different usernames", but conceptually how it is possible , can you elaborate that ?

Comment: Please post a new questions if you have more questions - a comment section is not the right place to have development talks

Comment: Ok, I have post the question here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43638/integrate-more-then-one-user-with-one-ethereum-account

You can refer it.