# Integrate more then one user with one ethereum account

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have many users inside the organization and I want to use same ethereum account for all the users , but with different usernames, so it there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If they all use the same private key they can use the same account. But Ethereum does not have a concept "username" - that's something that is between your contract and your backend system.

So let them all use the same private key and they will use Ether from the same account. Then it's up to your contract to decide how to distinguish the users - probably a username of some sort. This username needs to be configured in your off-blockchain code.

Comment: ok, got your point. Do have any reference link which gives proper idea about ethereum concept ?

Comment: Umh. There are a million sites for search "ethereum basics" for example. Read about the stuff which is unclear for you ans if you have some specific questions feel free to post them as new questions in this StackExchange

Comment: If I will use ganache-cli....and it is providing me 10 test accounts with 100ETH balance.

when I will close it and start ganache-cli again then it will give another new 10 test accounts.

so how to retrieve old account because i have used that account reference in whole application ?

Comment: Please consult their manual or ask a question in their support forum. Ganache is third-party software and this site is not aimed for that

Comment: What are the other options are available apart from Ganache?

Answer (score 0):

Multisig (multiple signatures) wallet is a common way to collectively own Ethereum address.  Basically, multisig wallet is a smart contract with several owners, which performs actions that collected enough owner approvals.