# Transaction fees in ethereum

Tags: ether, tokens, wallets, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created an ERC20 token, but whenever I want to trnasfer it, transaction fees is deducted in ethers. But I donot want to but ethers. Cant the fee be deducted in terms of my custom token?

Thanks

Comment: The transaction fee always is in ether

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand concept of Gas in Ethereum blockchain, Let's have a look to this [url](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)

The url has explained everything in detail. Every transaction in Ethereum blockchain is powered by Gas which take Ethers as fuel.