# How to do performance evaluation?

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, timestamp

How to do the performance evaluation in terms of secs or minutes? what is the command to use in solidity?

Answer (score 1):

You should not evaluate performance in time units. Your code will not even start computing immediately anyway so whether the actual execution takes 1 or 10 seconds doesn't make much difference.

What you *should* be interested in is how much gas your code execution takes as gas is the performance counter in Ethereum. You can read more about gas here: [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)

So even if you optimize your code so that it runs 10 times faster but costs 2 times more gas, your optimization has failed.

Comment: So, then how can i do the performance graph for 50 customers? please give me some ideas

Comment: I don't quite understand what you wish to do. What kind of graphs are you looking for?

Comment: I want to know the performance evaluation of smart contract for 50customers

Comment: for the evaluation we need the processing time for one customers.then, we can easily calculate the other customers

Comment: As I said, processing time is not something you want to evaluate. The processing time varies a lot and it's typically not much related to your code. Mostly it depends on other factors, such as gas price given for the transaction (decided by the one who calls the function). Even with static gas prices, the whole execution time varies a lot.

Comment: So,How can i calculate ?

Comment: particularly i need to calculate the processing time for the function append data and retrieve data

Comment: please give me some idea

Comment: the required latencies and the average number of transactions being performed in the system