# How do I know the gas and gas limit when sending a transaction?

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethereumjs

I am using below code to call a smart contract method on Ethereum network.

```
      const w = new Web3(url);
      await w.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
            {
              from: account.address,
              to: contractAddress,
              gas: 1000000,
              gasPrice: 1000000000,
              nonce: await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
              data: await contract.methods
                .createSector(
                  
                  { value: web3.utils.fromWei(price, 'ether') }
                )
                .encodeABI(),
            },
            privateKey
          );
```

In above code, it requires `gas` and `gasPrice` parameters. I need to set the value when calling the contract method. My question is how I know what the right value to set? I thought those values are not static which can be set during runtime when Metamask is open. Do I misunderstand anything on gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gas:` Mean how much your transaction will cost in gas if it executes. You can estimate your transaction before broadcast it to get estimation, and for safety you can increase a% from your estimation

`gasPrice:` try this https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_gasPrice

Or easier, use some library like hardhat, viem, ... , it can auto set for you

Comment: I mean those value is not static that could change anytime. If I put some estimate algorithm plus a% in the code, what happen if the gas is changed by the network?

Comment: gasPrice changed by the network.
gas changed by your transaction execution. Estimation mean you run it virtually on evm => it will return how much gas cost for that execution

Comment: If I set the `gas` price a little higher than the `getPrice` returned from the network, will the real gas charged by the network be lower than the gas set in the transaction? Will there be a return from the network to the charged account?

Comment: Gas and gasPrice are the not same unit of measure.

You can see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54606/what-is-difference-between-gas-gas-price-and-fee

Or I can give a simply example in life: `gas` => `how much gasoline for your car`
`gasPrice` => `price of gasoline`

Today, you want to drive to London, you will need 1000L gas, and gasPrice today is 5000¥/L

Nextday, you want to drive to Paris, 500L gas, and because of war gasPrice now is 7000¥/L

Comment: You can see, how much gas you cost belongs to how long you want to drive, mean how much code you will execute in evm.
And gasPrice will be changed by the network, how much previous txs pay for miner.

And about your question, you can set any value for `gasPrice` 
if lower than normal, your tx will be stuck, wait until gasPrice decrease to your value
if greater than normal, your tx will be broadcast asap

About `gas`, you must set the true value, if lower than it your tx will failed, if too much your balance can't adapt. Just enough

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. `just enough` is something very hard to hit

Comment: My english is not good to explain too much, but I'll give a try.

`very hard to hit`, in my opinion it's not.

I will give you an example in hardhat: your tx is `contractA.deposit()`. You can get estimation by `contractA.estimateGas.deposit()` => 80.000 gas

You can use that value in `gas`. But for safety, you don't want your tx fail because of over gas limit, you can increase 80.000 * 3% = 82400. 

You can see in every single tx on etherscan, see the value at `Gas Limit & Usage by Txn:`
Gas Limit is 82400 and usage by txn may 80020 (or any value)

Comment: Your `a%` is not too much, because if you want to set too much, your client address must adapt that balance. So you have to optimize that value due to your expectation.
Like if your common transaction is around 2$, 3$. 10% 20% is not too much,

If your common transaction is around 1000$, 1500$. 10% 20% is too much, 3%, 5% is reasonable

Comment: Your english is pretty straight forward to understand. Based on my understanding, the real gas I pay is between the `gasPrice` and `gas limit` right?

Comment: No. your real gas you used is a number around your `estimation` and must <= `gas limit`

And your real fee you pay in ETH is: `gas used` * `gas price` = ... ETH

The unit gas is: wei or gwei (1e9 wei)
The unit gas fee is: ETH