# How do i know how much eth the receiver will get?

Tags: myetherwallet, payments

I bought some ethereum a long time ago and I'm trying to buy something with it now. I want to make sure the address I'm sending it to gets a specific amount (say 2.00 ETH). When I enter the "amount to send" on MyEtherWallet, should i enter 2.00? Or is the gas/tx fee (don't really understand all this lol) which is specified below subtracted from that amount and so I should put 2.1 or something? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount that you specify in MEW when sending ETH **IS** the amount that the receiver will be credited *(you must obviously have the funds in the account you're sending from).*

The **[Gas Fee](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)** *(paid to the miners)* will be added to the amount you are sending. Its typically a small amount, only a few cents, which you can predetermine by using a website like **https://ethgasstation.info/.**