# Execution gas cost

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle

I use web3 and truffle to get info about my testnet transactions. There are few fields about gas used  per transaction, such as: gasPrice, gas, gasUsed.
But how to get field 'execution cost'?

Comment: Does `gasPrice * gasUsed` sound like what you need?

Comment: No, I need execution gas amount.

Comment: You need an special EVM like remix that can trace more details, there's no official api that provide such details for geth.

Answer (score 0):

The field `gasUsed` is your *execution cost*. All execution costs are denoted in units of *gas* in Ethereum.

`gasUsed` tells you how much gas the transaction actually used. This you can convert directly into Ethers (with the `gasPrice`) and if you want, you can convert Ethers into real-life currency (fiat) such as euros dollars.

You should read more about gas for example here: [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)

Comment: Yeah, I know about gas meaning. Your explanation is clear, but not complete. There is a case when tx cost isn't the execution cost. Appears when, as part of a transaction, storage is cleared with the refund of some amount of gas. You should read more about gas for example here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1048