# What is the meaning of "Gas Used" on ethgasstation.info?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price

It's rather confusing cos when I googled "gas used" I don't get any exact result, NOT even from ethgasstation.info and most people are talking about transaction price, gas limit, etc.

So, does "gas used" mean gas limit represented in Gwei? Like 21,000 gas limit or is it the average gas used per transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the site to estimate actual costs for your transaction. The site is not meant for calculating how much a transaction requires gas but it assumes that you already know how much gas a transaction takes.

The *Gas used* field takes your input and with that input you can estimate how much you actually have to pay for the transaction, given the gas price and gas used. It will also give you estimates about how fast the transaction might get mined.

21000 gas is the minimum gas amount for a transaction - if you only send Ethers to someone you pay 21000 gas but if you include any data (for interacting with a contract for example) the gas amount goes up.

You should read more about gas for example here: [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, "gas used" is basically my estimated gas limit that I expect to use right?

Comment: no, gas limit is the maximum gas you allow the transaction to use. gas used is known afterwards (or can be estimated) and means how much gas was actually used.