# Will gas be free in ETH 2.0?

Tags: gas, gas-price, eth-2.0

Will gas be free in ETH 2.0?

More generally, will gas ever be free? Is it feasible in near decades?

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gas will never be free. It has a purpose and that is to create a cost for a computation. If there was no cost for computation it would be possible to do infinite loops (with each loop being free) that would cause problems for the miners and system.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum 2.0 is starting out with the beacon chain: [What is the difference between Ethereum 2.0 and the beacon chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87238/what-is-the-difference-between-ethereum-2-0-and-the-beacon-chain)

You cannot make a transaction or run smart contracts on the beacon chain.  So gas doesn't apply.

In the future, when there are "eth2" smart contracts, there will be gas as @Zakoff and [others have explained](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas).