# Pending Transaction. How long may it take?

Tags: gas-price, pending-transactions

I have a question about this specific transaction: 0xd0dfbefc699ba79c2ddd86b0f7176e3e6491534db0a57597ec7aab9ce3e71726

the transaction is pending for some days now.
I offered 5 gwei as fee.
Max Amount of Gas 21.000

What will happen now? Will it be confirmed eventually?
How long may it take? Taking into account that the usual Gas prize is at the moment around 40 gwei or so.

I know that I could cancel or replace a transaction.
I do not mind waiting.
Maybe the gas price will drop if more people offer less ether/gwei?

Comment: Hey @nap, welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Your question can be paraphrased as "What is gas on Ethereum and how does it influence the time it takes to process a transaction?". And gas is already well-documented in this thread: [What is meant by the term “gas”?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas).

Comment: It will most likely be dropped and not added to the blockchain

Comment: How long will it take that a transaction will get dropped? Is there a general time out?