# doubts about ERC20

Tags: tokens, ether, erc-20, gas

I am learning to create my own ERC20 token following tutorials and managed to make a very basic one work but I still have doubts about issues that I do not understand, for example:

1. What is Gas and the Price of Gas.
2. If I am creating my own token because when I have to perform an operation for example a transaction I have to pay with etheruem so that it can be done.
3. How do I know what total supply I should create from my token

Any help or where you could investigate is welcome

Comment: For gas and gas price read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas

Comment: Total supply is usually an arbitrary number. Look at similar projects and use that as starting point.