# The cost of eth in the testnet is equal to the eth cost in mainnet?

Tags: ropsten, testnets, mainnet

i´m new in Ethereum development, i´m developing a Dapp in the Ropsten testnetwork but i need to pass it to the mainnet, have the sames cost? are equivalent in the moment we pass the Dapp to the mainnet? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> but i need to pass it to the mainnet, have the sames cost?

They have the same *gas cost*, meaning the same amount of work is involved in running code on each network.

However, the gas *price* is different. On the testnets the gas price is effectively 0 - testnet ETH is free.

On the mainnet ETH - and therefore the gas price - is not free.

See:

- [What is meant by the term "gas"?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-meant-by-the-term-gas)
- https://ethgasstation.info/

Comment: Thanks! ok, with your illustration i understand now the difference between gas and gas price, i understand now that the gas is a measure of the work involved in the transaction and the gas price is the cost of this gas, my answer now is: is necesary buy ether if we can deploy contracts in the testnetwork for our purpouse? because our Dapp bussiness not depend of the Ether price, because we only need deploy ERC721 tokens there.

Comment: The problem is that the test networks should only be considered as temporary. They can be reset at any time, and any balances or contract state would be reset.

Comment: Ok i understand, if the gas is equivalent in testnet and mainnet, we can see the real gas cost to determine the real Eth cost