# Etherscan Show Fail out of gas. Eth deducted. But transaction not completed

Tags: etherscan, contract-debugging, out-of-gas

I have enough ETH to pay the gas fee. After I click accept the transaction fail and it show out of gas on etherscan. Now the gas have been deducted but no transaction happen. Can someone help? The gas is not cheap.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x62f0a14a49eca7ce81b83596fc5cbab267a332e34b1dcc4b307c520baf4b8f12

Comment: You may have set too low of a gas limit. Read this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4614/24693).

Comment: but i use the default middle transaction in metamask

Comment: @LowKienYeat Did you try contacting OpenSea support? Some internal call failed. The transaction fees are always paid even when the transaction reverts.

Comment: @Ismael no I did not contact opensea. Many people I asked said is my problem. So after that I went to did the same transaction again. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x343e7ca357e74a2db28c390a276330578615b7c7c357ac61772784fec63eea28 this is the result. The Gas Used by Transaction: is 1,205,651. Comparing with my previous transaction is 1,200,000. Is a 5k difference. But my previous limit is 1,276,119. So I still dont know why the previous fail as not enough gas.

Comment: @LowKienYeat The gas parameter can be quite complex to estimate because it depends on the contract's state and if some other transaction changes the state before your transaction is mined it might fail. Sometimes I use an extra 10% just in case but there isn't a rule that will work every time, perhaps 10% is too much or not enough.